# Emulator on android studio

Tags: android

I am a new android developer I am trying to coding but when I start to check my app on the emulator it says the app is stopped what's wrong with my code?
it's the same code which tells me on the video to practice with it in the first tutorial.

enter code here

```
package com.technozoos.recyclingfacts;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class recycling_fact_activities extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView facttextview;
    private Button factbutton ;

    public recycling_fact_activities(TextView facttextview) {

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycling_fact_activities);

    facttextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.facttextview);
    factbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.factbutton);

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String fact = "Hello world this is CS50";
        Random randomGen = new Random();
        int randomNumber = randomGen.nextInt(50);
        facttextview.setText(randomNumber + "");
        }
    };

    factbutton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}
}
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. if there is an error with your code, its probably best to share with us that error. im pretty sure i know why, but the logs will tell me...or us... whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor with parameters? Why? .As you said us you are beginner, never write like this :) Show As your logcat message.You can see your crash in logCat